# Different conditions cause Crystal Report 11.5 report to not display

Tags: crystal-reports

I am creating this report using Crystal Reports 11.5 that is a look at our database values.  This means that users can select which tables to display and the report will show them all rows in that table (I realize this is not such a great idea but that's what was asked for).

The report is a collection of sub reports, one for each table. There is logic in the report that suppresses the sub reports based on a parameter passed in (control string).  Now here is where it gets fishy:  Some tables work just fine.  When I select to run them they display with no issues.  However, when I select certain tables the entire report is displayed as a blank page (which usually indicates an error in the report that is not in the code).  Depending on the table, these trouble tables WILL display under certain circumstances like if it is the **ONLY** table selected or if certain other tables are not selected or if I'm on my development box instead of a production server.  This makes no sense!

Let mention that the databases are the same. The control string that is passed in to hide/show reports is correct also. I have also attempted to rewrite some of these sub reports to varying degrees of success (not much success mind you).  Please, if someone has some insight on the issue let me know.

Comment: The issue may be that there are enough tables selected to cause the report to be more than one page and it is having an issue with that.  That would explain some of the behavior I have seen.  Hopefully this helps.

Comment: What I am about to say may not be immediately helpful, but I hope it will be of some use in the future: there are certain times when developers need to tell users that what they are asking for is a really, *really* bad idea. This report was one of them.

Comment: @ Mark: Ha! @ Sheek, how many subreports are there in total? 5? 10?

Comment: What if you just turned each subreport into a regular report? The end-user can just pick & choose which ones interest them. Would they go for that?

Comment: @PowerUser: HAHAHA no, more like 49. What a pain.

Comment: PS: They would never go for that solution.

Comment: 49? Good grief. Ok, um, how about an Excel file with 1 subreport per tab?